# Modifying WPA2 Protocol

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver, wpa, wpa2-psk, wpa2

I have flashed OpenWRT onto my Raspberry Pi Model 3B+ and was wondering if it is possible to modify how WPA2 works for example like changing the AES encryption into my own encryption algorithm or modifying the 4way handshake process?

Is this a hardware or software level thing and how can I go about doing it like is it possible to maybe change some code in the driver to edit the protocol?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you just trying to secure your network or do you really want to write your own communications protocols?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not easily. If you really wanted to do this you would also need to modify the client connection behavior of every device you would subsequently connect to this AP. That is also non trivial.

If you are interested in getting involved in how protocols are gloablly defined you would have to join the IEEE. You can read the full specification of the protocol as defined by the IEEE:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1318903

NOTE: It does cost money just to read text.

The good news is that there is an update coming called WPA3. You might need to buy new hardware that supports the new protocol.

It should be available to the public very soon, according to this source:

https://www.howtogeek.com/339765/what-is-wpa3-and-when-will-i-get-it-on-my-wi-fi/